# Having challenges installing pandoc-crossref in windows

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, junit-jupiter, pandoc-citeproc

I have recently started using `r markdown` and I am having issues with installing `pandoc-crossref` in window.

I have tried approaching friends on getting the set-up but to no avail. I have tried searching on the web but couldn't find anything useful. I tried following the directions here [text](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/releases/tag/v0.3.15.0) to no avail. I will be grateful if anyone knows where i can get the set up and how to go about installing it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any information about what errors you receive, so it is hard to provide useful help. This being said...

---

**Trying to guess what your problem is.** It is likely that you are getting the error `could not find executable pandoc-crossref` when trying to compile. Assuming that that is the case, your problem might be the following. Notice that `pandoc-crossref.exe` is not an installer, but an executable, so double clicking on it in an attempt to install it will do nothing except bring up a terminal for an instant. Is that what you have done? Where did you place it?

Leaving `pandoc-crossref.exe` e.g. in your `downloads` folder or on your `Desktop` would give the `could not find executable pandoc-crossref` error when trying to compile, because the executable needs to be in your `$PATH`, or pandoc will not be able to find it and run it.

---

**A possible solution.** If my guesses above are correct, you might be able to solve your problem by placing `pandoc-crossref.exe` inside your pandoc program folder, where your `pandoc.exe` file is, which is by default in:

```
C:\Program Files\Pandoc\
```

So try to place `pandoc-crossref.exe` in that folder and see if it works.

---

**If this does not help.** Say exactly what it is that you tried to do, what errors you encountered, and maybe include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RStudio and encountering the `'Could not find executable pandoc-crossref'` error, you should start by downloading the latest version of `pandoc-crossref.exe` from [this source](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/releases/). Once you have the file, place it in the same directory where Pandoc executables are located. To identify the directory RMarkdown checks, you can execute the following command:

```
rmarkdown::find_pandoc()
#> $version
#> [1] '3.1.1'
#> 
#> $dir
#> [1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools"
```